# Getting errors with malloc and realloc

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I am doing a Caesar cipher program in C. I already did the program but sometimes I get errors when running it.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


int main() {

    int size=10,al=0;
    int sizek=10,ak=0;
    char *str= (char *) malloc(size+5);
    if (str == NULL) {
        printf("malloc error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    char *strIni=str;
    char *str2= (char *) malloc(sizek+5);
    if (str2 == NULL) {
        printf("malloc error\n");
        return 0;
        }
    char *str2Ini=str2;
    //char a,b;
    while ((str[al]=getchar())!='\n') {
        if (al==size-2){
            size=size+10;
            char *strR=(char *) realloc(str,size);
            if (strR == NULL) {
                printf("malloc error\n");
                return 0;
            }
            printf("DDDD\n");
            strIni=strR;
        }
        al++;
    }
    printf("Or1 %d Al %d\n",strlen(strIni),al );
    str[al]='\0';
    printf("Af %d Al %d\n",strlen(strIni),al );


    while ((str2[ak]=getchar())!='\n') {
        if (ak==sizek-2){
            sizek=sizek+10;
            char *str2R=(char *) realloc(str2,sizek+5);
            if (str2R == NULL) {
                printf("malloc error\n");
                return 0;
            }
            printf("CCCC\n");
            str=str2R;
        }
        ak++;
    }
    printf("Or2 %d Ak %d\n",strlen(str2Ini),ak );
    str2[ak]='\0';
    printf("Af2 %d Ak %d\n",strlen(str2Ini),ak );


    printf("Str1 %s\n",strIni );
    printf("Str2 %s\n",str2Ini );

    int sDup=1;
    int dif[strlen(str2Ini)];
    int* dup=(int *) malloc(sizek);
    int max[(sDup)];
    int rot[2]={0,0};

    for (int i=0;i<(strlen(str2Ini));i++){   //pokud AA - aa -xy)
        if (str2Ini[i]<123&&str2Ini[i]>96 &&strIni[i]<91&&strIni[i]>64){
            dif[i]=(int)str2Ini[i]-((int)strIni[i]+6);
        } else if (strIni[i]<123&&strIni[i]>96 &&str2Ini[i]<91&&str2Ini[i]>64){
            dif[i]=(int)strIni[i]-((int)str2Ini[i]+6);
        } else if (strIni[i]<123&&strIni[i]>96 &&str2Ini[i]<123&&str2Ini[i]>96) {
            dif[i]=(int)strIni[i]-((int)str2Ini[i]);
        } else if (strIni[i]<91&&strIni[i]>64 &&str2Ini[i]<91&&str2Ini[i]>64){
            dif[i]=(int)strIni[i]-((int)str2Ini[i]);
        }
        if (dif[i]<0) {
            dif[i]=-1*dif[i];
        }
        printf("Dif%d: %d\n",i,dif[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(strIni);i++) {
        int l=0;
        for (int j=0;j<sDup;j++) {
            if (dif[i]==dup[j]) {
                max[j]++;
                l++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (l==0){
            dup[sDup-1]=dif[i];
            max[sDup-1]=0;
            max[sDup-1]+=1;
            sDup++;
        }
    }
    for (int h=0;h<1;h++){
        for (int i=0;i<(sDup-1);i++) {
            if(rot[0]>max[i]) {
                rot[0]=rot[0];
            } else {
                rot[0]=max[i];
                rot[1]=dup[i];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(strIni);i++){
        if (((int)strIni[i]>64 && (int)strIni[i]<91) || ((int)strIni[i]>96 && (int)strIni[i]<123)){
            continue;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Chybny vstup!\n");/*free(strIni);free(str2Ini);free(dup); */return 100;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(strIni);i++){
        if (((int)strIni[i]>64 && (int)strIni[i]<91) || ((int)strIni[i]>96 && (int)strIni[i]<123)){
            if (strlen(strIni)==(strlen(str2Ini))) {
                if ((int)strIni[i]+(int)rot[1]>90 && (int)strIni[i]<91) {
                    strIni[i]=strIni[i]+6+(int)rot[1];
                } else if ((int)strIni[i]+(int)rot[1]>122 && (int)strIni[i]<123) {
                    strIni[i]=(strIni[i]-58+rot[1]);
                } else if ((int)strIni[i]>64 && ((int)strIni[i]+rot[1])<91) {
                    strIni[i]=strIni[i]+rot[1];
                } else if ((int)strIni[i]>96 && ((int)strIni[i]+rot[1])<123) {
                    strIni[i]=strIni[i]+rot[1];
                } else {
                    strIni[i]='#';
                }
                //printf("%c ",strIni[i] );
            } else {fprintf(stderr, "SSError: Chybna delka vstupu!\n");/*free(strIni);free(str2Ini);free(dup);*/ return 101;
            }
    } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Chybny vstup!\n");/*free(strIni);free(str2Ini);free(dup);*/ return 100;
    }
    } 
    str[al]='\0';
    printf("Rot: %d\n",rot[1] );
    printf("String: %s\n",strIni );
    // free(strIni);free(str2Ini);free(dup);
    //freeIni, dup
    ///posun o 42pismen
    return 0;
}
```

I commented freeing allocated space because it was also giving me an error. I wanted to deal with it later.

All printfs excpet the last one are just for my control to know what this code does, and where it stops.

Sipmly code: I get 2 string in str and str2 with getchar. (Var al and ak are insted of usual i.) Then if they are bigger than (size(10)-2) I reallocate size+10. Then I work with strings and make the difference between chars. Then I look for the most used difference and use it as final rotation. After that I just rotate my 1st string with calculated rotation.

Input:

> qrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNnop 
>   
> aHcQefghWjdlmnopqostuvTxyYZ

Output:

> DDDD
>   
> DDDD
>   
> Or1 19 Al 27
>   
> Af 19 Al 27

Error:

> prog: malloc.c:2842: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (_rtld_global_ro._dl_pagesize - 1)) == 0' failed.

Excpected Output:

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS

Comment: What line of *your* code does the error refer to?  You'll need to check a stack trace.

Comment: You typically get errors like that if you write out of bounds of allocated memory. Maybe take some time with a memory debugger like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find the error.

Comment: By the way, what happens if `getchar` returns `EOF`?

Comment: Why so many casts? Why so may constant numbers? When you get to three levels of `ifs` you are doing something wrong.

Comment: This in a for loop `i<strlen(strIni)` is bad - why not `strIni[i]`?

Answer (score 2):

In your first loop, you realloc `str`, but don't assign the new value back into `str`, although you *do* access what `str` points to afterwards.  If `realloc` moved it (which it is allowed to do), this would cause a problem.  Similar thing w/ `str2` in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
char *strR=(char *) realloc(str,size);
```

you are reallocating `str`, but saving the new memory segment on `strR`. `realloc` may have to move the data, so the `str` pointer is potentially invalid.

Comment: The cast is not required - it is bad - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc